# Question on changing the APEX data load wizard to give default target columns

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Within the data load wizard that comes with APEX 18.1, after you choose your csv file to be uploaded you are offered a "TARGET COLUMN" drop down LOV which defaults to "DO NOT LOAD". It is possible to tell APEX which values you want in this LOV. I have done this.

My issue is, that this is quite laborious. Your users will not necessarily know which value you want them to pick from the LOV to map the related column when they are using a csv file with no header. As they are going to be doing.

Does anyone know how to change the "DO NOT LOAD" value in the LOV to another value? If I could get it to default to a column of my choosing, this would be great. Alternatively, there's a "SOURCE COLUMN" field in the wizard.

Getting the "SOURCE COLUMN" field to denote which column I wish users to map to the LOV value would be something also. Has anyone faced this before? Does anyone know if it is possible to do what I am suggesting as a work around? Thanks for looking and for your thoughts.

Comment: The whole purpose of the APEX data loader wizard is to allow end users to upload arbitrary CSV files where you don't know what columns they have and what order they appear. If you already know what columns they have, and what order they appear in, don't use the data loader wizard. Use a CSV parser to read the contents of the file directly.

Comment: Options to consider: https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2018/11/load-spreadsheet-data-into-apex/

Answer (score 1):

APEX does the column mapping automatically by checking the name of the column in the csv(the first row is names usually).

So if the names of the columns match in the table and the csv, it will connect them by itself. What you can also do is set column aliases.

If you want to edit the existing data load, you can go to Shared Components- Data Load definitions and pick the one you are using in there.

Then you can set column aliases there. But afaik you can only do one alias per column there.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, but I tried to explain (apologies if unsuccessfully, that's my fault) that the csv file has no header - so no column names. These are always the same, but, will have to be entered at upload by the users unless there's an alternative.  It's an alternative that I am seeking... I have already entered column name aliases within the Data Load Definitions. All it does is produce an LOV with a choice for a column name. The problem is, which LOV to select to map to a column is a mystery to the users. Which is why I'm asking what I am... seeking a means by which to make that better.